# SWI-Prolog: "Undefined procedure" error

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble to solve a Learn Prolog Now excercise (the last one in [this page](http://learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse12)). To make it short: there's a bunch of facts with the format "byCar (place1, place2)", "byTrain (place1, place2)" and "byAirplane (place1, place2)", and I have to write a travel/3 predicate (I called it tickets) that tells you which tickets to buy to travel from place1 to place2.

So for example, the query

```
tickets(valmont, losAngeles, X)
```

should return an answer like this:

```
X = goByCar(valmont, saarbruecken,
   goByTrain(saarbruecken, frankfurt,
   goByAirplane(frankfurt, bangkok,
   goByAirplane(bangkok, auckland,
   goByAirplane(auckland, losAngeles)))))
```

My current solution is:

```
ticketsDir(A, B, goByCar(A, B)) :- byCar(A, B).
ticketsDir(A, B, goByTrain(A, B)) :- byTrain(A, B).
ticketsDir(A, B, goByAirplane(A, B)) :- byAirplane(A, B).

swapGo(goByCar(A, B)) :- goByCar(B, A).
swapGo(goByTrain(A, B)) :- goByTrain(B, A).
swapGo(goByAirplane(A, B)) :- goByAirplane(B, A).

mergeGo(goByCar(A, B), Go2) :- goByCar(A, B, Go2).
mergeGo(goByTrain(A, B), Go2) :- goByTrain(A, B, Go2).
mergeGo(goByAirplane(A, B), Go2) :- goByAirplane(A, B, Go2).

tickets(A, B, Go) :- ticketsDir(A, B, Go).
tickets(A, B, swapGo(Go)) :- ticketsDir(B, A, Go).
tickets(A, B, mergeGo(Go1, Go2)) :- ticketsDir(A, Z, Go1), tickets(Z, B, Go2).
tickets(A, B, mergeGo(Go1, Go2)) :- ticketsDir(Z, A, Go1), tickets(Z, B, Go2).
```

However, that query returns this result:

```
X = mergeGo(goByCar(valmont, saarbruecken),
   mergeGo(goByTrain(saarbruecken, frankfurt),
   mergeGo(goByAirplane(frankfurt, bangkok),
   mergeGo(goByAirplane(bangkok, auckland),
   swapGo(goByAirplane(losAngeles, auckland))))))"
```

Now the odd thing is, the query

```
swapGo(goByCar(A, B))
```

returns:

```
Error: swapGo/1: Undefined procedure: goByCar/2
```

and the query

```
mergeGo(goByCar(A, B), go2)
```

returns :

```
Error: mergeGo/2: Undefined procedure: goByCar/3
```

It seems like I'm defining "swapGo" and "mergeGo" incorrectly, or perhaps "tickets". Any suggestions to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined anywhere a procedure `goByCar`? It doesn't look like you have, unless you are not showing your complete listing. And I have the feeling that you mean to say something like `swapGo(goByCar(A,B)) :- byCar(B,A)`, as you have defined those facts.

Comment: I'm showing all predicates. I didn't really define goByCar/2 or goByCar/3, but I want swapGo and mergeGo to always get a matching result. I'm using those two predicates as an auxiliaries to perform the swaps and mergers. If I deleted them, I'd have to write lots of tickets/3 lines, and code would get very messy.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment: if you have not defined a certain predicate, you can't be surprised that there is an "Undefined" error. Also, I tried to point out what you might actually be trying to say. I hope this helps.

Comment: RIght, I got it.So, any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: First, correct the offending `swapGo` by removing the undefined procedure from its definition (see my first comment). I don't know how else to say it.